# Relative positioning Top with percentage doesn't work for in-line element

Tags: html, css

In the following, the em is not repositioned if I use a percentage value for Top.  It works fine if I use px. Why?

I researched this in w3 and could not find any qualification on using percentage values.
The positioning context is the p - since its relative positioning - which should have Height derived from the line boxes.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I realise the work-arounds, but I am trying to understand the specification.  My experience so far is that there is generally some logic there even if its not immediately obvious. My aim with this question is to find out what is the logic in reconciling this behaviour with the specified behaviour in the visual formatting model.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: x-small;
        }
        div{
            outline: 1px solid red;
            background-color: silver;
            overflow: visible;
        }

        #test em {
            position: relative;
            color: red;
            bottom: -10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet, <em>duo ut dicant expetenda</em>. Laudem maiestatis eam et. Lucilius patrioque instructior et has. Sea at zril affert, mea accusam nominavi officiis te. Ad nam tota quidam mandamus, pro <em>dolor</em> veri volumus torquatos an.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When it comes to `relative` positioning, you should ask yourself *x percent of what*? In this case the `p` element should have some defined `height`, then it should work. It's a pity that it works that way, here is the demo showing it works by defining some `height` for the `p` element http://jsfiddle.net/8vtryb5j/

Comment: The positioning context is the `<em>`...relative means 'relative to itself.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, of course I asked myself _percentage of what?_ and when I researched the standard, it clearly stated _percentage of the containing block_ which is the p, which has a height defined by the anonimous line boxes it contains. I don't want to use pixels, I want to use percentage. And I do not want to fix the height of the p. Why would I do that?

Comment: But it's not the way CSS works. As I said *it's a pity*. If we can do like that, I think many problems relating to dynamic/flexible layout can be solved easily. Moreover, the defined height means the height declared explicitly in your CSS code.

Comment: @KingKing then how do you reconcile that with the standard? 9.3.2 clearly states that, for the Top property (inter alia) Percentages:   refer to height of containing block

Comment: @CoolBlue the containing block of the `em` element here is the `p` element, not the `div`. In fact I've not really refered much to standard documentation, all come from experience.

Comment: @Pauie_D the _movement_ is relative to the em, but the _length_, for a percentage value, is based on the height of the containing block. This is very clearly stated in the standard (9.3.2)

Comment: @KingKing yep, I understand that the p element is the containing block, but it has a height which is defined by the line boxes it contains.  So I'm trying to understand why _that_ height is not used to calculate the percentage offset.

Comment: Interesting. I noticed that if you target the element in Firebug and start to change values for `em` bottom property, it actually reacts.

Comment: I have to say that the specification is not much detailed enough. It talks about the properties (top, left, ...) but does not state clearly the 2 use cases: the absolute unit and the relative unit (percentage). All the examples also just involve absolute unit. The specification explaining the problem may be some where else. Anyway I have to say that **it's by design**. I've been experienced enough with CSS about this problem (it's very common) and I just followed the rule. The specification is just guideline for the browsers' developers implementing their code.

Comment: Percentage-based height-adjusting changes for inline (and inline-block) elements are usually quite hard to implement correctly: changing the container's height should be reflected in the containee's height, which in turn will affect the container... you see the picture.

Comment: Consider [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yeysza00/), for example. In Firefox 32.0.1, only the first `em` is adjusted, the second stays in place - my guess is that browser indeed recalculates the first one's position, but doesn't care for the second, as the style doesn't change. Is it correct? I guess not. But in Chrome both elements aren't affected at all.

Comment: @raina77ow your first comment: the em is _only_ repositioned if I use px units in Firebug. Your second comment: ... no, I don't see the picture. I am talking about about bottom and top, not height **and** I am talking about _relative positioning_ not absolute or float so your comments are not applicable: the unpositioned, normal flow space is preserved. Your third comment: I have the same version of Firefox and it does not position either.

Comment: @CoolBlue Erm, what? Ok, I made this demo [a bit more clear](http://jsfiddle.net/ksmrstru/); don't you see the first element shifted down the line, yet the second staying in place? In Firefox, I mean.

Comment: @raina77ow OK, I see it now... but only for the initial rendering. That's why I missed it before... If you adjust the size of the window the em jumps back to its in-flow position. It seems that JQuery is fudging the percent positioning but it is not persistent. Which suggests that JQuery is not successfully changing the CSS.

Comment: @CoolBlue Of course, jQuery does change the CSS - just check the element `style` attr. It's browser that doesn't care to apply that styling correctly onresize.

Comment: @raina77ow thank's for your patience but, I mean (after 50+ KB of incomprehensible javascript and injecting style attributes into the markup) jQueery has not succeeded in changing the behaviour of the CSS.  We are back where we started no? The browser does not deliver the formatting coded in the CSS.

Comment: are you trying to make <em> above the line or below it ?

Answer (score 3):

@Cool Blue,

Your reading of the specification is correct. A positioned element's offset as defined by `top` is calculated based on the height of that element's containing block (which in this case is generated by `<p>`). However, the problem you are encountering seems like a variation on a well known issue with the way browsers calculate the `height` property. [This problem typically occurs when we are trying to create an element that takes up the full-height of the viewport](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm).

The issue is that browsers don't bother to calculate the height of an element unless you specify an absolute `height` for an element on the page. Instead, browsers let the content flow within the width of the viewport until the viewport comes to an end. Thus, if you set `top: X%` on `<em>`, and the containing elements have `height: auto`, the browser does nothing. If you are going to use a percentage value for `top` (and if you only want to use percentages throughout the entire element tree) you must set the `height` of **every** ancestor to a suitable percentage.

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/jsp8y4jd/) is a solution that uses only percentages. Note that the effect is a bit uneven since changing the viewport size will change the offset of `<em>` relative to the text within `<p>`. So, while this is an interesting theoretical discussion, it may be better to set `top` in pixels from a design perspective.